# How to 'cycle' through the indexes of an associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

This is a `toggle` with 2 or more items, where the next item needs to be picked so that all values will be picked in turn.

The indexes in this particular associative array are unique, their number is variable (2 or more), and there are no prototype elements. I know the old index, and I want to set the new index to the next one found (or the first one if the old one happens to be the last).

This is what I came up with, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way. The associative array is `strings` and the old index is `oldx`:

```
var i, 
    seen_oldx = 0, 
    newx = "";

for (i in strings) {
  if (seen_oldx) {
    newx = i; // index after oldx (not reached if oldx is last)
    break; // found it, stop looking
  }
  else if (i === oldx) 
    seen_oldx = 1;
  else if (!newx) 
    newx = i; // newx is the first (in case oldx is last)
  }
}
```

Comment: 'new' is a reserved word in JavaScript, you can't use it as a variable.

Comment: please add the content of `strings`.

Comment: For example (but it really doesn't matter, and it can change, as long as there are at least 2 entries; the content could be any object):
strings = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}

Comment: please add some example, while object properties have no order how the "next" item should be taken.

Comment: The solution is my code is asuming that the the order in which for-in enumerates the indexes doesn't change when the object doesn't change. I'm fairly certain it can be relied on, but of course there is no guarantee from a specifications point of view. An even longer and cumbersome solution would perhaps take a one-time array of all the indexes and then cycle through that, incrementing the index modulo the number of them. That might be clearer & cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem a really elegant solution without adding another little data structure. I ended up adding a proper array of all the indexes of the strings associative array:

```
for (var i in strings) i_strings.push(i);
```

And then the code was just:

```
newx = (oldx + 1) % i_strings.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are describing a stack.  So you just pop the items off the stack as you need and there is no need for index, etc.

This is LIFO - last in first out

```
 var stack=[];
 stack.push(1);
 stack.push(2);
 stack.push(3);
```

Then to remove items

```
 var result = stack.pop();
```

Comment: What I had in mind was more a cyclic list. But the problem is how to elegantly link it to my associative array in code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with an array for the data and a property of the array `array.index` for keeping the last index and a function for returning the next element of the array.

```js
var array = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'],
    i;

function getNext(array) {
    if (!('index' in array)) {                // test if property index exist
        array.index = -1;                     // if not create one with start value -1
    }
    array.index++;                            // increment index
    array.index = array.index % array.length; // move the index into the right interval
    return array[array.index];                // return element
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write(getNext(array) + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I ended up adding a proper array of all the indexes of the strings associative array:

var i,
      j = 0;
for (i in strings) i_strings[j++] = i;

And then the code was just:

newx = (oldx + 1) % i_strings.length;

Comment: I wasn't aware you could 'overload' a normal array with non-positive-integer indexed elements, that can come in handy some time..! I guess that's really how all non-primitive objects work in javascript, they can have either or both.

Comment: the "normal" array is just an object with some special features.